# Link fails to render properly when rejecting an accepted edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, reviewing, formatting

I think a screenshot best conveys the bug:

[image: screenshot with a banner saying "This edit was already approved - please visit the post and correct the edit."]

As you can see, the link HTML in the drop down does not properly render:

> This edit was already approved - please visit <a href="/questions/246460/king-of-the-holster/246466#246466">the post</a> and correct the edit.

Comment: [Already reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377743), but supposedly [meta-tag:status-completed]??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! This is fixed now.